# Intellij couldn't resolve gradle version

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I just started learning gradle. Going right by guide, but when Intellij tries
to setup the project it fails, because it doesn't recognize gradle installed on my pc (I couldn't download it on every start, because corporate server doesn't allow such actions). I searched, but couldn't find what's wrong
gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=file\:///C:/Gradle/gradle-8.2.1-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

cache.properties
`gradle.version=8.2.1`

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
}

group = "org.NI_I"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Error stack trace

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve gradle:gradle:8.2.1.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve gradle:gradle:8.2.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-src.zip'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.staticResourceExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.artifactExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:67)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-src.zip'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-src.zip'.

    
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ������ - ��� ��������� ������, ����������� �� ����� ���������� ����� ����, � ����������, ��� ��������� ������ �� ������� ������ �� ������������ ������� (services.gradle.org)
    org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:184)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:160)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ������ - ��� ��������� ������, ����������� �� ����� ���������� ����� ����, � ����������, ��� ��������� ������ �� ������� ������ �� ������������ ������� (services.gradle.org)

    

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
```

I tried switching between recent versions of Gradle and switching Java, renstalling gradle, changing locations of folders, removing and adding dependencies and plugins and altering spring version

Comment: You probably don't need to escape the ':' in your distributionUrl, at least not where you did.